# What is the best way for a user to enter a date

Tags: android, user-interface, date

For my application, I have to get a date from the user.

I have try a simple `EditText` with the input type to `date`, but it's not very convenient for the user who has to enter himself the `'/'` character.

I have also tried the `DatePicker` component. It's more convenient than the `EditText` but it is big compared to others components like `EditText`.

Is there a best way for a user to get a date ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a button that displays the date and when clicked shows a `DatePickerDialog`.

Comment: I didn't know there was a dialog like this. I will try this. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Ohhh haha I didn't understand why you couldn't just use DatePicker. I get it now, you didn't use the DatePickerDialog as well. :P

Comment: @Vinay I have a form with different components like `EditText`. If I integrate the `DatePicker` in this form, the `DatePicker`, as I said in my post, is too big compared to the others. With the DatePickerDialog, in my form, I can have a simple EditText. I prefer having a new dialog permitting the users to enter the date in a simple way without making my form looking ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [`DatePickerDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) that is triggered by "Change" button next to `TextView` field with currently selected date.

Answer (score 0):

So did you not want to use DatePicker? I'm a bit confused by your problem, since there isn't necessarily a "best" way to get a date, it's based on your preference and situation. If you would like an alternate way to get a date, you could have 3 separate EditText Views that take in the Month, Day and Year and get that information with a "submit" Button or something of that nature. Or you could look into Spinners. [Here's](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-spinner-example) and example.

Answer (score 0):

For keyboard entry I normally prefer a maskedit box. If the interface is for touch or mouse you might want to include a drop down calendar.